# Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'

Tags: android, gradle

This is a warning message I am getting while using Room. I could not find anything here. Anyone knows what this is?

Thanks in Advance